# An unbelievably talented protagonist who re-creates technology from scratch and wins the girl

Tags: story-identification, e-e-doc-smith

I'm trying to identify a story I read as a child. I vividly remember it as being by E.E. "Doc" Smith, but reading the synopses of the *Skylark* and *Lensman* series, it doesn't seem to be any one of those. Perhaps it's one of the *Family D'Alembert*, or perhaps I've mis-remembered the author?

The protagonist was ridiculously handsome and talented (something along the lines of: he played quarterback for a Superbowl winning team and he was a billionaire businessman and a Nobel-winning scientist). He crash-lands and is stranded on a primitive planet with a beautiful woman as his only companion, and has to re-create the technology of his ship from scratch (mining and smelting ore, all the way up to building a completely new ship).

During this period, he fights off the primitive natives and rescues his companion after they've captured her. They fall in love, but do nothing until they can escape so that he can ask her father for her hand in marriage.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is likely Smith's [*Spacehounds of IPC*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?11454) (serialized *Astounding* 1931, novel 1947); after a crash the hero has to build a hydro-electric dam to recharge the accumulators in order to operate the radio to call for help.

Quoting from the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacehounds_of_IPC#Plot_synopsis):

> The Inter-Planetary Corporation's (IPC) space-liner, *IPV Arcturus*, takes off on a routine flight to Mars. **Brilliant physicist Dr. Percival (“Steve”) Stevens** is aboard to validate the work of the ship's pilots in response to reports by the Check Stations of errors in the ship's flight positions. To his relief, he confirms that the pilots are right, and it was the Check Stations that were out of position, not the ships.
>
> Before the *Arcturus* can reach Mars it is attacked and literally cut into pieces by a small, mysterious, globe-shaped spaceship. The attacking spaceship begins towing the pieces toward Jupiter. **Stevens and a female passenger named Nadia Newton end up stranded** in a large, wedge-shaped piece of the dismembered ship. They work to repair as much equipment as they can, gathering needed material from other pieces of the ship floating nearby, and start calling the piece they are in the *Forlorn Hope*. As they approach Jupiter, Stevens eases the *Forlorn Hope* out of the pack and manages a hard landing on Ganymede, a moon of Jupiter.
>
> With the remains of the *Forlorn Hope*, Steve has everything he needs to construct an ultra-radio set capable of reaching the inner worlds and calling for help. But the landing discharged the accumulators, and with no power, they must be recharged before anything else can be done. **While Steve uses the ship for raw materials to build a hydro-electric power plant and a power beaming station to recharge the accumulators**, Nadia explores the area around where they landed.

In addition to being a mathematics genius and a physicist, Stevens is an Olympic athlete (diving):

> "Oh, of course—Stevens, the great Olympic high and fancy diver! I would *never* have connected our own Doctor Stevens, the eminent mathematical physicist, with the King of the Springboard.

The bit where she asks her father for permission to marry (thanks to OP for finding this):

> "Dad, I've been thinking a lot since you rescued us, and what we've just heard has given me the nerve to say it. Steve, of course, wouldn't dare suggest such a thing until we're safely back on Earth, so I will." Her deep brown eyes held his steadily. "All those girls got married—why, some of them have babies already—and Steve and I have waited for each other *so* long, daddy! And *none* of them love each other the way we do. Do they, Steve?"

You can read the entire story at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/20857/pg20857-images.html).

Comment: I always appreciated the unblinking realism that Doc Smith brought to SF.

Comment: @MarkOlson I was skimming the story looking for quotes, and...  I just couldn't force myself to go on.  _Wow_.

Comment: This gem sealed it for me: "Dad, I've been thinking a lot since you rescued us, and what we've just heard has given me the nerve to say it. Steve, of course, wouldn't dare suggest such a thing until we're safely back on Earth, so I will." Her deep brown eyes held his steadily. "All those girls got married—why, some of them have babies already—and Steve and I have waited for each other so long, daddy! And none of them love each other the way we do. Do they, Steve?"

Comment: @MarkOlson particularly the way the Earth scientists can analyze advanced tech and develop even more advanced tech in a week or two.